# Using scrollview on tabactivities with table layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Im developing an android-app which is basicly three tabs each tab with its own activity class. Here is the main.xml:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TabWidget>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <include layout="@layout/sorted_teams" />
        <include layout="@layout/unsorted_teams" />
        <include layout="@layout/about" />
</FrameLayout>        
    </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

I have three includes each with its own activity class and layout xml file. What I want is a scroll on the content of each tab. How would you go about this? I tried enclosing the entire content of the layout files for the different tabs with a scrollview. I use tablelayout for the content of every tab. I tried eclosing the entire content with a scrollview but it wont show up. How would you recommend using scrollview if I want the content scrollable for each tab?

Answer (score 0):

Use a ScrollView as the enclosing parent of TableLayout in each layout file of each of your tab activities.

Make sure your scroll-view definition is similar to

```
<ScrollView
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick answer! The solution you posted was my solution too but I had missed one detail that seemed to screw everyting up.

I tried again with enclosing everyting with a scrollview in each layout but I had fill_parent on layout_height, changing it to wrap_content seemed to fix everything, problem solved!

I dont know why we set it to fill_parent, I think it was because some issue with the background color.